# How to find the location of a web application root directory from within my application?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, registry

List of installed applications from Registry, are often, retrieved from here

> Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

The location of the programs can be retrieved from the relavent subkey "InstallLocation". However, this seems to not apply to windows and web services.

Windows Services location can be retrieved from

> SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services

How can I find information about Web Services and their location from registry?

Comment: Why not just use IIS api?

Comment: @mahlatse, Can it be consumed pragmatically? Any link?

Comment: Yes, let me post the solution for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration(v=vs.90).aspx) can be used to query IIS, you can do things like,

1. Get List of all websites
2. Get info about a specific Website
3. Get info about web applications in a website
4. Get info about the binding in an application
5. Create/Modify, etc a website
   ....

A simple usage example would be

```
private ServerManager serverManager
        {
            get
            {
                if (_serverManager == null)
                        _serverManager = new ServerManager();


                return _serverManager;
            }
            set { _serverManager = value; }
        }
```

and you can use the above variable to get a specific site name

```
var site = serverManager.Sites.First(x => x.Name.ToLower() == siteName.ToLower());
```

where you can get the site names from `serverManager.Sites`

You can also open application webconfigs and modify,query,etc

```
public static System.Configuration.Configuration GetConfigurationFrom(string appName, string hostName, string site)
        {
            return System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(@"/" + appName, site, null, hostName);
        }
```